# CSS background: repeating-linear-gradient tweaking

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to tweak some css code - repeating-linear-gradient to be precise.

Here is my current code:

```
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
    #ccc, 
    #000 10%, 
    #ccc 1%, 
    #000 10%, 
    #ccc 10%, 
    #ccc 20%
);
```

Here is an image for how it looks:
[image]
And this is what I want to do:[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following css:

```css
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
    #ccc 9%, 
    #000 10%, 
    #ccc 1%, 
    #000 10%, 
    #ccc 10%, 
    #ccc 20%
);
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it!

```
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
    #ccc 9%, 
    #000 10%, 
    #ccc 1%, 
    #000 5%, 
    #ccc 10%, 
    #ccc 28.5%
)
}
```